# A minimisation problem in an Hausdorff space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let X an hausdorff space, K a compact set, f a lower continuous function. How can you prove that f has a minimum on K?

Ps: be careful X is not specially a metric space

Answer (score 2):

Use that a function is [lower semi-continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity) if and only if all of its lower level sets $f^{-1}(-\infty,t]=\{x \in X : f(x) \le t\}$ are closed.

Let $a=\inf f(K)$ (either a real number or $-\infty$). Look at the family 
$F=\{K\cap f^{-1}(-\infty,t]: t>a\}$. This is a family (ordered by set-inclusion) of non-empty closed and hence compact subsets of $K$, and hence it has a non-empty intersection. Take any $x$ in the intersection, then $f(x)=a$, hence $a>-\infty$ and the minimum is achieved.